# Rails 5.2 AngularJS and html templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Can't seem to figure out how to make the asset pipeline play nice AngularJS template files for components which like this:

```
app.component("chart", {
 templateUrl: "./templates/chart_element_tpl.html",
 controller: ChartElementController,
 bindings: {
    accounts: '='
 }
});
```

I've looked at the various posts on this problem here but none of the suggestions seem to work. I always get the 404 error.  One of them talks about upgrading sprockets to version 2.x but I am on version 4 already.

I have taken care to make sure my template has a different name than the javascript file as suggested in another post, but none of these things quite seems to do the trick.

FYI, the structure of the assets  relevant assets directory is:

```
app/assetsjavascripts/chart_component.js
app/assets/javascripts/templates/chart_element_tpl.html
```

It does seem weird to me that an html template is stored in the javascripts folder but that seems to be the way people do it.  I also made sure to include the directory in the applications.js manifest with

```
//= require_tree ./templates
```

I tried things like `assets:clean` and `assets:precompile` and `yarn install` and restarting the server but none of that seems to solve the problem.

I also have installed the angular-rails-templates gem and required it in application.js, also no help.

It does make sense to me that this is failing because the actual files are versioned etc. in the public directory, but not sure what to do about that so AngularJs can find my templates.

Comment: are you using gem 'angular-rails-templates' ?

Comment: I have the gem installed, and I am including it in my applications.js.

Comment: if you use the default values of options for that gem # config/application.rb
config.angular_templates.module_name    = 'templates'
config.angular_templates.ignore_prefix  = %w(templates/) you should add angular.module('myApplication', ['templates']) and have a path like this  templateUrl: "chart_element_tpl.html", without ./templates which is a ignored prefix